At some oment I got error MySQL configuration not found. How to fix it?
In some moment my MySQL server stopped working(I have installed my home kubuntu 22.04  several months ago)
I check commands :
# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
root@master-at-home:/path# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)
root@master-at-home:/path# sudo service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.
root@master-at-home:/path# systemctl status mysql.service
× mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-10-27 09:33:42 EET; 10s ago
Process: 32412 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
CPU: 2ms

master-at-home systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
master-at-home systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
master-at-home systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
master-at-home systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
master-at-home systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
root@master-at-home:/path# journalctl -xeu mysql.service
░░ The job identifier is 3931 and the job result is done.
master-at-home systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3931.
master-at-home mysql-systemd-start[32412]: MySQL configuration not found at /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Please create one.
master-at-home systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStartPre= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
master-at-home systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
master-at-home systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 3931 and the job result is failed.
master-at-home systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
master-at-home systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4065 and the job result is done.
master-at-home systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
master-at-home systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
master-at-home systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4065 and the job result is failed.

I found line :
 master-at-home mysql-systemd-start[32412]: MySQL configuration not found at /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Please create one.

I have no /etc/mysql/ subdirectory at all. I do not know why so and how restore /etc/mysql/my.cnf in my OS ?
uname -a
Linux master-at-home 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I decided to upgrade my OS but got next errors in messages :
path# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro InRelease
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/giuspen/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openswoole/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
path# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  php-common php-mcrypt php-mongodb php8.2-mongodb php8.3-mcrypt php8.3-mongodb
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Setting up elasticsearch (8.15.3) ...
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-env: line 78: source: /etc/default/elasticsearch: is a directory
dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--configure):
 installed elasticsearch package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 elasticsearch
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Are these issues related ? How that can be fixed ?
I have default my sql instllation, without any specific options...
UPDATED :
path# sudo apt install --reinstall mysql-server-8.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for mysql-server-8.0:amd64
path# sudo apt install --reinstall mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for mysql-server:amd64

UPDATED # 2:
# sudo apt purge mysql-server-8.0 && sudo apt install --reinstall mysql-server-8.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl libfcgi0ldbl libhtml-template-perl mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
mysql-server* mysql-server-8.0*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1 713 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 288059 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up elasticsearch (8.15.3) ...
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-env: line 78: source: /etc/default/elasticsearch: is a directory
dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--configure):
installed elasticsearch package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
elasticsearch
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I still have no /etc/mysql/ subdirectory at all.
UPDATED # 3:
I exit toot :
whoami
master

Run commands :
master@master-at-home:path$ sudo apt purge elasticsearch && sudo apt install mysql-server-8.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl libfcgi0ldbl libhtml-template-perl mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
elasticsearch*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1 179 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 288042 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing elasticsearch (8.15.3) ...
Stopping elasticsearch service... OK
(Reading database ... 286653 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for elasticsearch (8.15.3) ...
dpkg: warning: elasticsearch: conffile '/etc/default/elasticsearch' is not a plain file or symlink (= '/etc/default/elasticsearch')
Deleting security auto-configuration directory...OK
dpkg: warning: while removing elasticsearch, directory '/var/lib/elasticsearch' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing elasticsearch, directory '/usr/lib/systemd/system' not empty so not removed
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
mysql-server-8.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1 386 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1 603 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 286641 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.28-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
grep: /etc/mysql/: No such file or directory
Unpacking mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu4) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Please clarify and confirm you details; Ubuntu (including Kubuntu) didn't have a release in 2022-May (22.05) thus your release makes no sense, you're also using a unsupported kernel from an EOL release (6.5 was from 23.10), so are you using Ubuntu? or have made mistakes in your question & left your system unpatched for some time?

sure 22.04 version

I suggest applying security fixes asap; 22.04 used the 6.5 kernel at 22.04.4 (it was from 23.10) but switched to 6.8 (from 24.04) as the HWE kernel stack when 23.10 reached EOL as part of the 22.04.5 changes... You're behind on applying security fixes from your details; using an unpatched and unsupported kernel for 22.04 (GA = 5.15, HWE = 6.8, OEM = ...)

Is it related to my problem ?

Can you try sudo apt install --reinstall mysql-server-8.0? Maybe just creating my.cnf would suffice, however it would be empty, and the installation could be borked otherwise for what we know.

(if it doesn't work, please add the output of the command to the question)

Is format of your commands valid ? Please lokk at UPDATED

I see, try and purge / reinstall. sudo apt purge mysql-server-8.0 && sudo apt install --reinstall mysql-server-8.0 (it won't delete your databases)

@kos careful. he IS going to that on a root prompt. mstdmstd: stop using root and NEVER use sudo with # as you did.  exit the root shell, restart mysql, read what is says. and delete all in the question that uses # sudo. Those are incorrect usage of a sudo based OS

@Rinzwind What's the issue with doing that from a root prompt? I'm not seeing it, please point it out :|

@kos, please look at UPDATED # 2

By the way Rinzwind is right in that it'd be safer to get off the root prompt and run things as an unprivileged user. Please do that from now on. I would say try and purge elasticsearch as well at this point? Unless you need it? If you don't, sudo apt purge elasticsearch && sudo apt install mysql-server-8.0

@kos, please look at UPDATED # 3

@mstdmstd see the contents of /etc/my.cnfit likely has/etc/mysqlin there (that file gdoes not get removed when uninstalling mysql unless you use purge)  You could also mkdir it yourself if you want to try that. Or remove /etc/my.cnf if you do a sudo apt install --reinstall mysql-server-8.0

Alright, I guess you'll have to try and create the file, sudo touch /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf, then sudo apt install --reinstall mysql-server-8.0.

Thanks! Last commands fixed the issue!

Nice, does cat /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf show something though? Or is it empty?

Just empty output

Creating /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf (even as an empty file) and reinstalling MySQL should work:
sudo touch /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf &&
sudo chmod 0644 /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf &&
sudo apt install --reinstall mysql-server-8.0

After that, I'd advise restoring it to the default version of the file, as /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf normally sources the contents of /etc/mysql/conf.d and /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d;
Here's the default /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf for MySQL 8.0.39 on Ubuntu 24.04.2 (although I don't think this file ever even changes across versions - remember to run sudo systemctl restart mysql after restoring the file):
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

